# Stock price from json file in Java

Tags: java, json

I need to read value of stock from a JSON file in Java this is the file

```
 {"name":"UCG.MI", "history":
    {"2019-05-16":{"op":"1","cl":"2","h":"2","lo":"1","vol":"10"},
     "2019-05-15":{"op":"1","cl":"2","h":"2","lo":"1","vol":"10"},
     "2019-05-14":{"op":"1","cl":"2","h":"2","lo":"1","vol":"10"},
     "2019-05-13":{"op":"1","cl":"2","h":"2","lo":"1","vol":"10"},
     "2000-01-04":{"op":"1","cl":"2","h":"2","lo":"1","vol":"10"},
     "2000-01-03":{"op":"1","cl":"2","h":"2","lo":"1","vol":"10"}
    }
}
```

I'm able to get "name" using org.json

```
json = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("UCG.json")), "UTF-8");

 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);

 String pageName = obj.getString("name");

 System.out.println(pageName);
```

Someone can help me to read the rest of the file ?

I try

```
JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("history");

for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {

    String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("op");

}
```

But I get errror

> org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["history"] is not a JSONArray.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use Jackason framework and create your model for this Json and you can convert from Json string to respective model.

Comment: Always use json viewer for help http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ @CAF Learn the difference between json array and json Object. History is an json Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because `history` property in the JSON is not an array but an Object. Try the following section instead of the one you already have

```
JSONObject history = obj.getJSONObject("history");
for (String date: history.keySet()) {
  JSONObject post = history.getJSONObject(date);
  String postId = post.getString("op");
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, History is a JSON Object. Secondly, History contains an object with six Key(String)-Value(JSONObject) pair.

Above logic is implemented here.

```java
    JSONObject history = (JSONObject) jsonObject.get("history");
    Set<String> dates = history.keySet();

    for(String date:dates)
    {
        JSONObject details = (JSONObject) history.get(date);
        System.out.println(details.get("op"));
    }
```

Note: I have used json-simple java library here.